# What Types of Books Are Best Suited as a Debut Novel for a New Author?

Tags: publishing

I've been writing and editing and getting thorough and objective feedback for a portfolio of novels I've written since 2016, and I will be speaking with an editor at a major Christian publishing house as well as agents who represent Christian fiction this year. But I am in doubt as to which novel I should focus on presenting to them as my debut. I have a list of brief synopsis' or elevator pitches for you all to choose from and I would like your input. Which books should I promote first as my debut?

**A FATHER'S JOURNEY TO PARADISE (98,000 Words) - Christian Speculative Historical:**

A deadbeat father, living in New York City during the 1920s, unexpectedly dies and enters a retro-futuristic afterlife on the brink of collapse as he tries to reunite with his departed kids to be a father he never was.

**ISA (70,000 Words) - Christian International Suspense/Thriller:**

While living in Saudi Arabia, an exiled persecuted Christian tries to reunite with the love of his life with a bounty on his head.

**STATE OF GRACE (56,000 Words) - Christian Coming-of-Age (Older YA) Speculative:**

A girl enters Purgatory as she explores the meaning of life and everything in-between. While suffering from her traumatic past, she wrestles with her identity and unbelief before her fate is tested in being damned to the Inferno.

**FLIGHT 365 & OTHER STORIES (60,000 Words) - Christian Coming-of-Age (Younger YA) Speculative:**

FLIGHT 365 - PART OF A NOVELLA COLLECTION - Stranded on a deserted island in the South Pacific, a group of teenagers’ struggles to survive as they seek to build a raft in order to set sail to New Zealand. Until, they suddenly encounter a mysterious force that scatters them all into a strange world torn apart. A place where the righteous and unrighteous go to be judged. A place where the shades greet you when you come and a place that inspires dreams in this suspense-filled fantasy adventure based in the Jewish afterlife: Sheol.

JOSHUA - PART OF A NOVELLA COLLECTION - A young boy is dropped into a strange world torn apart. A world where the righteous and unrighteous lie after death. He meets a group of orphaned children who guild him through before later meeting an adventurous girl as he and that girl embark upon a journey across this world. They then encounter a mysterious person who wants to rule this world, a person known as the Adversary before a series of cataclysmic events unfold.

**ICON (53,000 Words) - Christian Coming-of-Age (Younger YA), Historical Fantasy:**

Twelve Tribes. One World. One Icon. Two siblings of a dying tribe meet a young boy in a cave, but when that boy reveals himself to be the ICON, a person who holds special abilities begotten by the Spirit of G-D who’s meant to bring peace to the world. They journey with him across a world of elemental magic and wonder as they’re followed by a ruthless tribe who wants to control and oppress a broken world. A world that is separated by G-D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations on the vast amount of writing you've embarked on over the last four years! I've read the synopsis to your titles and whilst the underlying themes may appear familiar (good overcoming evil) the craft lies in how twisted and complexly your plots evolves. I love that the settings are varied and also the main characters. 
Settings and culture do have a way of presenting even the same stories with voices unique to context. Personally, I'd say go with the last one (not too sure if the title is catchy enough for YAs though)  or title with a setting that is most unfamiliar to your current location (or publisher) with well researched content. 
Also have a look at recent books your publisher has released into the market and try to present yours as more unique. YA christian fiction is much needed! 
I hope this helps. Wishing you great success!

Comment: Thank you, Sade! I will definitely consider querying ICON to agents and publishers today. I am quite thankful for having two thoughtful proofreaders for without them, I would have probably abandoned my works.